# You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server

Tags: php, authentication, openid

I made a 'login with OpenID' page and I had a error when OpenID provider return to my page:

> You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
>        Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

If I remove parameters which are returned by OpenID provider, the page run well. How can I fix this problem? The login page that cause error is: `http://bryox.com/login`

Answer (score 1):

The login page you link to seems to actually be located here: `http://bryox.com/gate/login`

To fix this you could add

```
$route['login'] = "gate/login";
```

to your `/application/config/routes.php` or alternatively make a `login.php` controller with its `index` method as a copy of the `login` method in your `gate` controller.

Answer (score 0):

404 errors generally means the page can't be found.  Check to make sure your error document is actually in the location you specified.

Sometimes it can be something as simple as including a leading slash.  For example, if your custom error page is on your website root and it's called `notfound.htm`, you should put  `ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.htm`.  If you forget the slash, the webserver will look for a `notfound.htm` in the current directory. In case you do not have such a file, a default 404 page will be served.  You can define your custom error pages in the .htaccess file.

Comment: However if he removes the parameters the page is found. So it's not a simple case of the page not being there.

Comment: I'm not sure why my answer was voted down.  From what I gathered from his post, he's saying, there's two problems. I was only addressing his second problem--the 404 error--which is not directly related to the first problem.  It sounds like he's getting a 404 because his custom error pages are either not where he defined them or they don't exist. So, when he uses the OpenID w/ parameters, something is causing an error--which is then being caught by his custom error page.  However,  his custom error page doesn't exist, is misspelled, or in another folder, so he's now getting a 404 error page.

Comment: He calls it one problem with a two line error message. Yes, there are two problems, but the first one is the tricky one.